# Not able to take a build using SBT for a Simple spark application

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to take a build for a simple spark application using SBT

While taking the build using sbt package from the project directory it simply hangs for few minutes and then i got the below error

```
n1@edge-node DEV $ pwd
/home/cloudera/test/spark/SimpleSpark
n1@edge-node DEV $ find .
.
./src
./src/main
./src/main/scala
./src/main/scala/SimpleSpark.scala
./build.sbt
n1@edge-node DEV $ sbt package
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
            module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8

    ==== local: tried

      /home/cloudera/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8!sbt.jar:

      /home/cloudera/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/jars/sbt.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-  sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Also I tried to get the version of sbt installed in my cluster and I get the below message alone, nothing happens after that

```
n1@edge-node DEV $ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.8
```

I would like to know what went wrong here .
I am new to sbt . 
Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a version mismatch. The SBT version that was available in your desktop needs to be updated. its looking for 0.13.8 version of SBT. Please check donwload include in your PATH and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: @ Bala : I tried executing this command in my cluster  and I get the below hanging ,                n1@edge-node DEV $ sbt -version
Waiting for lock on /home/cloudera/.sbt/boot/sbt.boot.lock to be available...

Comment: This is a different issue, The file is locked meaning some other application is using the file. So, you might want to check and restart the system if thats a option.

Comment: Yes, After restarting I tried giving n1@edge-node DEV                       $ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.8                                                                            So this means sbt is installed in my cluster, but still I get error when I run sbt package